# Rails3 Associations and nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, nested-attributes

I am having trouble when it comes to saving/creating 2 objects at once and associating them to one another. Currently I am doing it in a 'hackish' sort of way by not using nested forms and just passing the parameters for both objects separately (from the view.) Then I connect them in the controller here is my code:

**Models**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :product
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :product, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :post
end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
        <div id="post_field">
            <%= f.text_area :content %>
        </div>
        <div id="post_link_previewer" class="clearfix">
        <%= fields_for :product do |prod| %>
            <%= prod.text_field :name %><br />
            <%= prod.text_area :description, :rows => 2 %><br />
            <%= prod.text_field :image_url %><br />
            <%= prod.text_field :original_url %>
        <% end %>
        </div>
        <div id="submit" class="clearfix">
            <%= f.submit "Post" %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
```

**PostsController**

```
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @post = @user.posts.create(params[:post])
    @product = Product.create(params[:product])
    @post.product_id = @product.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to(root_path, :notice => 'Post was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

So when a user makes a post, they can attach a 'product' to that post if they want. The current way I am doing it makes a lot of sense. When I looked at nested form tutorials and see them using build methods I start to get a little confused as to what is going on. Can you help me understand the best way of linking these 2 objects upon create? Is it best to use nested form fields? I feel the current way I am doing it isn't as efficient as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use nested forms. There is a reason as to why they were built. They ease the process of managing associations and creating nested objects in a single go.

The `build` method builds an object (it calls the .new() method for the object) and then you can use it.

I advise you to start with a simple example of nested forms and play around with it for an hour or two. This way, you'll have a better understanding of what's happening underneath.

I think, in this case, self-learning by playing would help you a lot, instead of someone just telling you why nested forms are better.

To get you started, refer to [nested-attributes-in-rails](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes).

Comment: thanks! By going through it again and using the build_association method I found out my critical mistake, I had the foreign key on the wrong table doh!